# How can I open a solution file from powershell?

Tags: visual-studio, powershell

I'm new to powershell and I'm looking to create a powershell script to open two different solution files with two different versions of visual studio.  I have the commands for opening up the different visual studio versions, but not sure how to open the solutions with each one. Here is what I have so far.

```
$vs19 = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" 
$vs19WorkDir = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\"
$vs15 = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"
$vs15WorkDir = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\"

Start-Process $vs19 -WorkingDirectory $vs19WorkDir
Start-Process $vs15 -WorkingDirectory $vs15WorkDir
```

Comment: Just add the path to the solution file as the first argument: `Start-Process $vs19 -WorkingDirectory $vs19WorkDir -ArgumentList "c:\path\to\solution.sln"`

Comment: Thanks! This fixed it, if you want to make this the answer I'll approve it!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Although not super obvious at first glance, the [`devenv` command line reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/devenv-command-line-switches?view=vs-2019) mentions:

> - When specifying a solution or project, the **first argument is the name of the solution file or project file**, including file path.

With this in mind, I tried the following against Visual Studio 16 (2019):

```
& "path\to\devenv.exe" "path\to\a\solution.sln"
```

and it opened the solution in question, so you should be able to do it with:

```
Start-Process $vs19 -WorkingDirectory $vs19WorkDir -ArgumentList "c:\path\to\solution.sln"
```

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a Powershell script to solve this problem. It was inspired by @Mathias R. Jessen's answer. You can find it on this Github [gist](https://gist.github.com/AmSmart/c8dd1b604695866fc26601c66bef60ea)

EDIT:
I shared the gist on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/dotnet/comments/k3unp8/opening_visual_studio_from_powershell/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) as well and it turns out that there are much cooler and intuitive ways of achieving this on PowerShell. Check them out as well.

PS: `The fastest method I've seen so far is by typing `*.sln`, then hitting `Tab` and `Enter`

Comment: Is it too long to share here?

Comment: It's a bit long, in my opinion, it'd make the answer look a little ugly